# Woocommerce query for pending orderd

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want a mysql query to get all my orderd on pending status. Somebody know how to do that.

I'm using woocommerce ina wordpress website, but I just want the mysql query not with wordpress functions.

Thanks

Comment: show us what you tried..

Comment: I have no idea how to do it :(

Comment: why the mysql query and not the wordpress one?  If you're doing this IN wordpress, it is safe to use Wordpress functions.  Even wpdb::prepare, which accepts a normal SQL

Comment: Well we need a mysql query beacause we are working on a custom report.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well  I spent the weekend working on the query and here is the result:

```
select
nombre,apellido,direccion,direccion2,codigo,poblacion,provincia,correo, telefono
from (
    select
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_first_name") as nombre,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_last_name") as apellido,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_address_1") as direccion,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_address_2") as direccion2,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_customer_user") as codigo,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_city") as poblacion,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_state") as provincia,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_email") as correo,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_phone") as telefono

from
wp_posts AS p
    WHERE post_type = "shop_order" and id in (SELECT object_id
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id 
WHERE post_type = "shop_order" 
AND term_taxonomy_id=9
)

) A
```

Comment: Definitely bad practice to write a custom query for this sort of thing when it can be so easily achieved in the proper way. Regardless of what custom functionality you need, the regular WP_Query (and related methods) can pull the data you need.

Comment: Pete what about when you need this outside of WP?

Answer (score 1):

You really should use the built-in database functions since that complies with the [Wordpress coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#database-queries).

You could look at the [WC_Query](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Query.html) class.

Or you could try something like the below.  You will need to change the meta key to whatever the meta key is they are using.  Also the meta value might be different than pending and the post_type may be different than 'shop_order'.

```
    $pending = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => array('shop_order'),
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'   => 'status',
                    'value' => array('pending'),
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Here is [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366999/woocommerce-query-order-items-by-product-meta?rq=1) on how to do a meta query of woocommerce orders.

Comment: Hi CmDZ thanks for your answer. We are working on a custom report. I mean the main website is running with wordpress+woocommerce but we want to generate a custom report for commercial purpose and this report will not be running on wordpress. Will be running on ASPX so we need to get those orderds from the mysql datababse and create a CSV file.

Comment: In that case you will be pulling data from multiple tables since that is how WP stores CPTs.  It may be easiest to generate the report on the WP installation on regular intervals using wp_cron and save it to a file there.  You could also setup a script that could only be accessed by the other server and the data could be passed that way.  Depends on the amount of data and how often.  Many variables here.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, it is a weird issue, but I fixed it by simply using a custom query. Somehow adding `'post_status' => 'wc-pending'` doesn't actually change the query, but if I use `pending`, the query changes.

So what I did was using that custom query and modify pending to `wc-pending`.